# The Gradient descent different between in Ng coursera and Michael A. Nielsen book

Tags: neural-network, gradient-descent, backpropagation, learning-rate

I am learning the neural networking from NG machine learning course in coursera and the book neural networking and deep learning by Nielson. I have a little confusion about the understanding of the Gradient Descent. I see two different formals to update weight by the Gradient Descent between NG and Nielson.

from Nielson:

[image: the weight update formula]

[the chapter Two, section The backpropagation algorithm](http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com/chap2.html)

from NG:
[image: the weight update formal]

both of them are used to update weights after forwarding pass in the backpropagation algorithm. in Neil version, it seems there is a learning rating -η in NG version, it does not have any learning rating, and it more like the learning rating is +1. I am very confused on this. is there anyone can help me to understand it?

Comment: I misunderstood. NGs formula just calculates gradient, not for weight. more tails about [NGs formula] (https://www.coursera.org/learn/machine-learning/supplement/pjdBA/backpropagation-algorithm)